# How to integrate opentelementry with nestjs and graphql

Tags: graphql, nestjs, open-telemetry

I tried the below code in which I can see traces related to database queries / file system / HTTP calls but it now showing graphql resolver name. Am I missing something, I am using Nestjs GraphQl Module

```
// tracing.js
'use strict';
const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-node');
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http');
const { Resource } = require('@opentelemetry/resources');
const { SemanticResourceAttributes } = require('@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions');
const { GraphQLInstrumentation } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation-graphql');
const exporterOptions = {
  url: 'http://localhost:4318/v1/traces',
};

const traceExporter = new OTLPTraceExporter(exporterOptions);
const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter,
  instrumentations: [
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations({
      '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-graphql': {
        allowValues: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'node_app',
  }),
});

// initialize the SDK and register with the OpenTelemetry API
// this enables the API to record telemetry
sdk.start();
```